# Print a Json object in browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, file

I have a json object present in a file which I need to print on browser using basic html. It is already pretty-printed in the text file. I want to get it the same on the browser.

Comment: show some code. we cannot guess your code

Comment: You just want to open your json file in browser, instead a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
var json = {"employees":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]},
    code = document.getElementById('output');

code.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre>
  <code id="output"></code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of angular:

```
<div>
  {{jsonData | json}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to get the string on the page, just worrying about the formatting, you can fix that by using `<pre>`

```
<pre>
Your
    pretty
          JSON
</pre>
```